# Restrict User Impersonation in Git Extension

Tags: git, authentication, gitlab, git-extensions

We're using Git, Git Extension and GitLab with a team of developers.

In *Git Extension > Setting > Git Config*, **User name** and **User email** are entered to record author to local commits. When the developer push local changes to central repository, the name of the author is shown as per author history in local commits.

It seems we can enter **any** user name and email and commit locally and then push to central repository. This effectively give me a chance to impersonate any user. I'm sure this is not acceptable environment and I'm missing something.

What we want to avoid is inadvertent commits with incorrect user details, unintentional or intentional, specially when the developer has separate official and personal emails. I believe the git work flow is based on a philosophy of trust and openness and it works pretty well in public projects. In official developments, we need an audit trail without any user discretion.

I'm not able to identify a way to restrict such impersonation and restrict commits to authorized user only during local commits and push to remote repository. Can you please suggest right way forward?

Comment: The assumption in git (like any DVCS) is that only trused users are allowed to push to the repository, and trusted users would by definition not falsify author information. Since commit creation and commit pushing is separate in a DVCS (unlike a centralized VCS), there's no way to check at push time whether the authorship information is correct (unless you sign commits).

Comment: I understand the point and appreciate the information. What we wanted to avoid is inadvertent commits with incorrect user details, _unintentional or intentional_, specially when the developer has separate official and personal emails. I believe git work flow is based on philosophy of trust and openness and it works pretty well in public projects. In official developments, we need audit trail without any scope of user discretion. I guess this might be subject matter of different approach/ solution. I'll research more on signing options. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I edited it into your question, as it helps to understand what you are looking for - feel free to re-edit if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author information is not for authentication.  If you need to be able to *prove* who contributed a commit in an environment where people you don't trust can contribute, then you need to sign your commits.  See the `git commit` docs, particularly for the `-S` / `--gpg-sign` option

Comment: To add to that, Linus lists good reasons to _not_  sign commits. Read this before you sign your commits: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/GPG-signing-for-git-commit-tp2582986p2583316.html

Comment: @jsageryd - Meh.  Linus is very opinionated that what doesn't meet *his* needs is worthless. That doesn't mean he's always correct.  He makes some valid points about limitations of directly signing commits, and the potential merits of signed tags.  And yet, if you look at the context of that very post, (1) it was from 2009, before the `commit -S` option existed; (2) it was from a discussion about some devs wanting the `-S` option, and (3) the option did, in fact, get implemented, notwithstanding Linus's feeling that the options at the time were already better.

Comment: I thought the information may be useful. Here are two threads discussing the addition of `commit -S`: https://public-inbox.org/git/7vaaa8xufi.fsf@alter.siamese.dyndns.org/ ; https://public-inbox.org/git/7vaa9f3pk8.fsf@alter.siamese.dyndns.org/. The information from these threads does not necessarily invalidate the arguments stated in the thread mentioned above.

Comment: And GitExtensions is able to sign commits. It's in the `option` dropdown of the commit form...

Comment: I understand the point and appreciate the information. What we wanted to avoid is inadvertent commits with incorrect user details, _unintentional or intentional_, specially when the developer has separate official and personal emails. I believe git work flow is based on philosophy of trust and openness and it works pretty well in public projects. In official developments, we need audit trail without any scope of user discretion. I guess this might be subject matter of different approach/ solution and I've got enough pointers. I'll research more on signing options. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Correction to what @Philippe said - Git Extensions v2.51 (the official version at the time of writing) provides the ability to sign tags. The next version will provide a UI to sign commits as well.